# Displaying a Javascript clock in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a clock using the below code and want to display it in my HTML webpage.

Such as `Todays current time is:`

How would I go about that? thanks.

```
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xx2ce/3/

First of all you want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Also just fixed other bugs with your code

Here is the code:

```
function startTime() {
    var d=new Date();
    var h=d.getHours();
    var m=d.getMinutes();
    var s=d.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Todays current time is: "+h+":"+m+":"+s;
}

function checkTime(i) {
    var j = i;
    if (i < 10) {
        j = "0" + i;
    }
    return j;
}

setInterval(function() {
    startTime();
}, 500);
```

for HTML all you need is this:

```
<p id="txt"></p>
```

and the clock will tick... magic eh? ))

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

The time is:<div id="txt"></div>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
startTime();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use onload?  Why not just place the script tags right before `</body>` and run it from there?

Comment: I wasn't sure if he required just the site with the time or not. I'll edit it of you want :)

Comment: It doesn't matter what else is in the page.  These `<script>` tags can be placed right before `</body>` and you can have anything else in the  page you want.

Comment: Edited to allow for better site.

Comment: FYI, `setTimeout(function(){startTime()}, 500)` can be `setTimeout(startTime, 500)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you Go:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/bU2R4/)

```
<body onload="startTime()">
```

or

```
window.onload=startTime;
```

Hope this helps.